# UIImageScanlineFloodfill - Flood fill C code to return only color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, flood-fill

I'm using this code:

[UIImageScanlineFloodfill](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill/blob/master/UIImage%20Scanline%20Floodfill/UIImage%20Scanline%20Floodfill/UIImage%2BFloodFill.m)

to do a UIImage color Flood fill and everything works great. It's filling the area I want with the color I want.

Next step is to get a new image with only the color filled and not the rest of the image. Preferably with a transparent background. I've tried some stuff but without success since my C skills are very limited. Any suggestions on what to do?

Update:
I've managed to recreate the flood fill by doing the following:

Adding the points to an array:

[pointsArr addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(x, y)]];

Then recreate the pixels like this:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.originalImage.size, NO, self.originalImage.scale);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    NSValue *valu = [arr firstObject];
    CGPoint prevValue = valu.CGPointValue;
    for (NSValue *value in arr) {

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, prevValue.x, prevValue.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, value.CGPointValue.x, value.CGPointValue.y);

        prevValue = value.CGPointValue;
    }

    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);

    UIImage *floodFilled = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGContextRelease(context);
```

But this makes the process really slow on a high res image. Up to 20-30 sec. I tried it with a UIBeizerPath as well but it's even slower. It goes fairly fast if i use a linewidth of 1 but then it gets some white spots. Would love some help.